# How can I point XMLHttpRequest towards custom OnGet type custom handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, xmlhttprequest, razor-pages

I am writing web app which needs to update fields according to  state.
I have written static part in Razor Page. 
i have also a piece of script which sends request and updates fields upon receiving answer.
I am stuck at the point of telling script where to send request to. I have custom handler called OnGetAsyncTimesStamp in .cshtml.cs file. What should my

```
xhttp.open("GET", "Details?handler=AsyncTimeStamp", true);
```

look like?

script:

```
@section scripts 
{
    <script>
        function TimestampChangedFunction()
        {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                //if(this.readyState == 4 %% this.status == 200){
                    document.getElementById("MachineType"      ).innerHTML = xhttp.responseText; 
                }
                xhttp.open("GET", "Details?handler=AsyncTimeStamp", true);
                xhttp.send();
            } 
    </script>
}
```

handler:

```
namespace ProjectName.Pages_Machines
{
    public class DetailsModel : PageModel
    {

        (...)
    public JsonResult OnGetAsyncTimeStamp()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("AJAX request received");
       List<string> lstring = new List <string>
       {
        "Val 1",
        "Val 2",
        "Val 3",
        "Val 4",
        "Val 5",
        "Val 6",
        "Val 7",
        "Val 8"
       };

    return new JsonResult(lstring);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the code that you posted? If so what happens?

Comment: It works.....
I had a problem with proxy anf therefore requests could not get through.
However I now look for way to call custom handler with argument 
id=A234958034, Any ideas? :-)

Comment: Add it to the query string `?handler=MyHandler&id=10` or use a route template: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods